# Get Dropdown Element Value by Text

Tags: jquery

I am working in a legacy application where I am in the obligation of getting the value of an option by the option text instead of the other way like usual.

Here is a non working example that I need help with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var optionText = 'Two';
    console.log($('#myselect option[option="' + optionText + '"]').attr("value"));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var optionText = 'Two';
     v = $('#myselect option')
    .filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == optionText; }).val();  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
$('#myselect').find('option[text="' + optionText + '"]').val();
```

Comment: This is what the duplicate post says...  Rather than duplicating answers, vote for the duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it depends on the version.
Here is what worked for me:

```
$('#myselect option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Two"; }).val()
```

Thanks